# Create alert box using erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alert, ruby-on-rails-7

I want to display an alert box when user wants to delete a post using button_to "delete".

I tried an onclick function but failed.

```
<div class="card my-5">
  <div class="card-body">

    <h1 class="text-center"><%= @post.title %></h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="my-4">
      <%= simple_format(@post.content) %>
    </div>
    <% pre_like = @post.likes.find { |like| like.user_id == current_user.id} %>
    <% if pre_like %>
      <%= button_to 'Dislike', post_like_path(@post, pre_like), method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= button_to 'Like', post_likes_path(@post), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= @post.likes.count %> <%= (@post.likes.count) == 1 ? 'Like' : 'Likes'%></p>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <% if @post.user_id == current_user.id %>
        | <%= button_to 'Edit', @post, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        | <%= button_to "Delete Post", onclick: "delete()", post_path, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see.
Well this is an example that I used to display an alert from the browser if the user clicks on the delete object.

```
<%= button_to "Delete", my_path, id: "delete_btn", method: :delete, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } }, class: "myclass" %>
```

You have to use turbo_confirm on **button_to**, for Rails 7 apps in this case.

I hope this helps.

Comment: nope , it still deletes without an alert